# AVCaptureSession runtime error when another app is capturing a video (NSOSStatusErrorDomain -12983)

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession

My app records a video by using AVCaptureSession. It works fine unless other app is using camera as well (e.g. start video call in Zoom, open the app, start capture session). In that case by starting capture session my app gets the following runtime error

```
AVCaptureSessionRuntimeErrorNotification, object = Optional(<AVCaptureSession: 0x282c242b0 [AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720]>
    <AVCaptureDeviceInput: 0x282e42c20 [Back Camera]>[vide] -> <AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x2820af750>
    <AVCaptureDeviceInput: 0x282e42c20 [Back Camera]>[vide] -> <AVCapturePhotoOutput: 0x282e4c0c0>
    <AVCaptureDeviceInput: 0x282e43680 [iPhone Microphone]>[soun] -> <AVCapturePhotoOutput: 0x282e4c0c0>
    <AVCaptureDeviceInput: 0x282e42c20 [Back Camera]>[vide] -> <AVCaptureVideoDataOutput: 0x282e48ac0>
    <AVCaptureDeviceInput: 0x282e43680 [iPhone Microphone]>[soun] -> <AVCaptureAudioDataOutput: 0x282e480a0>), userInfo = Optional([AnyHashable("AVCaptureSessionErrorKey"): 
        Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed"
        UserInfo={
            NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12983),
            NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed,
            NSUnderlyingError=0x2820a2490 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12983 "(null)"}
        }
])
```

Re-starting capture session leads to the same error. I found that `-12983` error code stands for Core Media Session error indicating "Insufficient Priority": https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/10422

Is there any way to specify priority for AVCaptureSession or maybe there's some other way to make capture session works even if other app is also capturing the video? (I haven't found any way to specify priority for AVCaptureSession or any other AVFoundation object that's used for video capturing)